# Не могу установить ориентацию экрана Android приложения

Tags: android, android-manifest, orientation

Нужна только портретная ориентация экрана. Прописываю в манифесте в элементе `<activity>` параметр `screenOrientation`:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

По итогу, при повороте эмулятора genymotion, приложение все равно переходит из портретной ориентации в альбомную и обратно. Что я делаю не так? :)

Хочу добавить, что `activity_main.xml` содержит в себе `AppBar` и `FrameLayout`, который отображает фрагмент. Мало ли это важно :)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эмуляторы не смотрят на манифест. Тестируйте на реальном девайсе

Comment: Ничего себе. Я не знал даже. Т.е. все мои действия, которые я описывал, верны? Просто прописать портретную ориентацию в манифесте и все? :)

Comment: @YaPV, конечно :D просто попробуйте на устройстве

Comment: Все работает исправно :) Затупил я, но вам спасибо !)